# Which Apple app condenses day names into weekday and weekend?

Tags: ios, ui, alarm

There's a somewhere in one of the Apple apps where they condense the days of the week into "weekdays" or "weekends" etc. can't find it. Any idea? I'm trying to mimic this in one I my apps but I can't find the behavior to examine it.

Which Apple app condenses day names into weekday and weekend? Is it calendar? Reminders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Alarm Clock on iOS.

When you create an alarm, and set it to only repeat on the Weekdays or Weekends, the Alarm overview page will display the appropriate term.

[image: Alarm Clock List Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

After searching a little more thoroughly, I realized that this occurs in the iOS Clock app on the iPhone and iPod touch. When setting an alarm repeat, if all days are selected, they become "Every Day". If only all the weekdays are selected, it shows "Weekdays". If only Saturday and Sunday are selected, it shows "Weekends".

Comment: Rawr, I was getting a screenshot but iPhoto is being WAY too slow. I even have very similar text in my clipboard right now. (Why not just give up and e-mail it to myself? Who knows. Cut the Cord!)

Comment: If you post a screenshot, you get my upboat. I was too lazy to send myself one.